# Laravel Validation: use single field to validate a set fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I have two fields that FormRequest is expecting to receive as a set: `image_id` and `image_path`.

However I want to only return a single message using the field `image_path` when the FormRequest receives a wrong input.

For example, `image_id` is string, or `image_id` is null, both are null, `image_path` is plain string etc.

Which ever error Laravel decides is an error, I would like Laravel to only say that  `image_path is required` or `image_path is not a url` or `image_path is not set correctly`. (Custom message not required)

current validation rule:

```
$rules = [
    'image_id' => ['required', 'integer'],
    'image_path' => ['required', 'url', 'min:2', 'max:500'],
];
```

If I set it up as is, the user would receive two error validation message.

**Note** as per comment, I am unable to use `$stopOnFirstFailure` since it will also stop other validation errors. Also if the validation is on `image_id` the return error message key will be `image_id`.

Comment: set protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true; in formrequest class

Comment: @JohnLobo this would work if and only if I only have these 2 fields. But aside from these two, I also have other fields that I need to validate. If I add `$stopOnFirstFailure`, it will also stop other validation errors which I do not want.

Comment: Do you want if error in `'image_id'` then the error should be in the form of `image_path` ?